# MFC slider increment decrement with mouse wheel

Tags: c++, mfc

I have implemented a slider in my application with MFC. slider has range 0 to RAND_MAX. it currently jumps with 655 units of steps with mouse wheel.

can some body tell me how I can set slider increment decrement with mouse wheel by just one unit

Comment: You are probably looking for `CSliderCtrl::SetLineSize`. The default is one hundredth of the range, if I recall correctly, which is likely where 655 is coming from: `65536 / 100`. Or maybe `SetPageSize`; I don't remember which one of them is used for mouse wheel.

Comment: ya, I know about them but what values should i put in them ?????? i tried setlinesize(4096) and setpagesize(4096) but it didnt work.

Comment: If you want to increment by one, I imagine you want `SetLineSize(1)`

Comment: thats not working ... SetLineSize(1)

Comment: also SetPageSize(4096) with SetLineSize(1)

Comment: Did you read through [Using CSliderCtrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/using-csliderctrl)?

Comment: yes, it doesnt say any thing about mouse wheel any where, plz find if you can...